# Subscripted value is not an array (error)

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I was writing some code in C++. At a certain point (line 44: `cout << commands_help[i];`) it says there is an error: "Subscripted value is not an array"... In fact I used a list, not an array... In the function "help()" I print every item of list `commands_help` with `\n` between every item. How can I do it?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream file;

// variables and arrays
string shell_symbol;

bool get_texture(){
    file.open("UsedTexture.txt", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open()){
        file >> shell_symbol;
        file.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        cout << "unable to open file";
        file.close();
        return false;
    }
}


list<string> commands_help = {
    "'help' ________________ Display this help page.",
    "'[command] info' ______ Display command purposes.",
    "'datetime' ____________ Can show date, time and calendar.",
    "'exit' ________________ Quit the MiSH."
};

long help_size = commands_help.size();

// functions / commands

int help() {
    int i = 1;
    commands_help.sort();
    while (i < help_size) {
        if (i < commands_help.size()){
            cout << commands_help[i];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    if (get_texture()) {
        string inp1;
        cout <<
        "\nThis is the MiSH, type 'help' or '?' to get a short help.\nType '[command] help' to get a detailed help.\n";
        while (true) {
            cout << shell_symbol;
            cin >> inp1;
            if (inp1 == "help" || inp1 == "?") {
                help();
            } else if (inp1 == "exit") {
                break;
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `operator[]` with a `std::list`. Maybe you want to try with a `std::vector`, or use a `for` based on iterators instead of your while.

Comment: Switch from `std::list` to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). `std::vector` should always be the default container. A list makes no sense here, and as you noticed you can not use subscription with a list.

Comment: Also, note that like arrays a vector starts its indexing at zero.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the switch from list to vector has caused many errors

Comment: Then fix those errors? Like I said, the default container should always be `std::vector`. Only change to another container if you need what they bring, and can live with the drawbacks that comes with them (like no subscription for `std::list`, and need to use `std::sort` instead of a member function).

Comment: Actually, in your case since you have a fixed-size "array" of strings, then I suggest you use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `iterator`. An `iterator` is like a pointer to an element in a STL container. For example:

```
int help() {
    list<string>::iterator it = commands_help.begin();
    while (it != commands_help.end()){
        cout << *it << '\n';
        it++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modern compiler, C++ 11 will do most of the work for you already:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> commands_help =
{
    "'help' ________________ Display this help page.",
    "'[command] info' ______ Display command purposes.",
    "'datetime' ____________ Can show date, time and calendar.",
    "'exit' ________________ Quit the MiSH."
};

void help()
{
    for (auto line : commands_help)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    help();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what about `return ... ;`?

Comment: Good question. While C++ would return 0 in this case, I'm not in favor of defaulting that way. You need no return, so why have the function return anything. `void` would be a better type, I'll edit that.

Comment: i tried your code without a function (directly on `main()` function and on `commands_help` say " '<unnamed>' is not a valid range type" and on each items of commands_help say "excess in scalar initializer"... whay should I do?

Comment: I've expanded the example to incude a full, compilable program. This works with 0 errors using VS2015.